# Can't get JUnit test to fail (it should)

Tags: java, file, junit, save

I have the following code in a JUnit test (only including the relevant parts)

```
private String testRoot = System.getProperty("user.home");
private String destFail2 = testRoot + "/GoogleDrive/TestFail//..\\...//*";

@Test
public void given_NamedParameterizedFileSet_when_SavedWithInvalidFileName_then_Exception() {
    String invalidFullPathToFileSet = fsPathDir + invalidBackupName;
    //test save fully parameterized empty file set at non-existent directory
    try {
        FileSet fs = new FileSet(backupName, dest);
        try {
            FileSet.save(invalidFullPathToFileSet, fs);
            fail("Save name is invalid, should refuse save");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            assert(true);
        }
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        fail("Could not create the file set");
    }
}
```

The code for FileSet.save() is as follows:

```
public static void save(String fullPathToFile, FileSet fileSet) throws IOException {
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    Path outFilePath = Paths.get(fullPathToFile);
    Path outDirPath = outFilePath.getParent();

    if (Files.exists(outFilePath)) {
        Files.delete(outFilePath);
    }
    if (!Files.exists(outDirPath)) {
        Files.createDirectories(outDirPath);
    }
    try {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(new
                BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(outFilePath)));
        out.writeObject(fileSet);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

The FileSet.save() method above SHOULD fail because it's being given what I *think* is an invalid file name, but somehow the code runs just fine without throwing an exception (on a Mac; haven't tried it on Windows).

1. Why is the code running?
2. Given the code, where do I look for the file it created?
3. What kind of filename do I need that is "bad?" I tried creating one with a colon (:) in it as it's supposed to be the only illegal character on a Mac, but even that works and it ends up creating a file with a colon in the middle of the name...
4. Is there a "better" way to write FileSet.save() (rather than using Path, should I be using File and passing the path in to the constructor as a string)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, don't use `assert` keyword - if you run the java application without `-ea` parameter ("enable assertions"), this line will not execute at all. By the way `assert true` does nothing.

Secondly, exceptions that you do not care about, those that you are not testing, like `e1` shouldn't be caught, declare that test method throws it. It will reduce the unnecessary complexity.

Finally, I would recommend using `ExpectedException` to do this assertion:

```
@Rule
public final ExpectedException expectedException = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void given_NamedParameterizedFileSet_when_SavedWithInvalidFileName_then_Exception() throws Exception {
    String invalidFullPathToFileSet = fsPathDir + invalidBackupName;
    FileSet fs = new FileSet(backupName, dest);

    expectedException.expect(IOException.class);

    FileSet.save(invalidFullPathToFileSet, fs);
}
```

This allows you to also check a message. It also checks that the exception is thrown after `expect` line. So if `new FileSet(...)` throws IOException, the test will fail. Note, `ExpectedException` needs to be annotated as `@Rule` to let junit now to perform a check at the end of test.

Comment: Excellent suggestions - I wasn't aware of that @Rule. I will definitely use that. However, it still didn't solve my issue. The problem is that FileSet.save() isn't throwing an exception and it SHOULD. I've stepped through the code with debugger and it does in fact execute the out.write() method successfully, though for the life of me I cannot find the file it seems to be creating... Take a look at the FileSet.save() and see if you can figure out why it's working given what should be a "bad" filename being passed to it...

Comment: @Greg What is exactly this invalid path? Is its directory valid? e.g. for `dir1/dir2/invalid_name.exe` if `invalid_name.exe` doesn't exist, nothing will fail, the method will create a file in `dir1/dir2`. The original path is used only to check whether file exists and if it does, delete it.

Comment: "Invalid" really means "contains illegal characters for the underlying concrete file system." At a high level, I'm trying to make sure that if you give save() a path that has illegal characters in it, or to a path that is otherwise "unreachable" (like trying to go to Q:\ on a Windows box that has no Q:\ volume active), throws an exception. I think the core issue is that I'm not coming up with illegal paths, hence it's working. I can't seem to find a path (or filename - either one) that is "illegal" and then causes an exception as a result.

Comment: @Greg so is your invalid path starting with `Q:`?

Comment: I am also a bit concerned about what you are testing here. User/developer tries to use your `save` method. If the given path is correct, file will be created. If system for some reason cannot create the file, it will probably fail on `Files.newOutputStream` - but this is not your code and you shouldn't be testing it. If it interprets special characters  differently and creates a file in unexpected place - that's again not your problem.

Comment: Ok, that helped actually. I had tried changing the "testRoot" to "Q:" but that would then cause the FileSet constructor to throw an exception (the constructor validates the destination, which was also "bad" with a "Q:" in front of it. I created a new variable for the bad save() path and the test is now working. THANK YOU for working through this with me - it's been driving me crazy.

PS: your last comment about testing the outputStream is spot-on as I think about it. Thank you for that as well - I hand't even considered that.

Answer (score 0):

The test is successful because of improper exception handling. In the inner `try-catch`:

```
try {
  FileSet.save(invalidFullPathToFileSet, fs);
  fail("Save name is invalid, should refuse save");
} catch (IOException e) {
  assert(true);
}
```

The line `FileSet.save(invalidFullPathToFileSet, fs);` throws an exception and for this reason the next line, which should fail the test, is not executed and the execution flow is redirected to the `catch` block where you simply `assert(true)` (which is a completely useless statement in a unit test) and then exit the inner and then the outer `try-catch` blocks, leading to successful execution.

What you should do is something like:

```
try {
  FileSet.save(invalidFullPathToFileSet, fs);
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  fail("Save name is invalid, should refuse save");
}
```

This will fail the test whenever an exception is thrown.

Comment: You shouldn't swallow the exception completely though, it should be logged or something.

Comment: This is the opposite case, OP wants to assert that exception is thrown.

Comment: See my comment to Jaroslaw Pawlak. The test itself is one issue for sure, but I modified it using both yours and Jaroslaw's suggestions separately and the problem is really that FileSet.save() isn't throwing an exception when it should (the filename it's being given should cause an IOException due to being illegal, but it's not)